# Storing and Retrieving the data to the Internal Storage Error ,Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

**So I am trying to store the data to my internal storage and Retrieve it back, So when I try to retrieve the data back it retrieves the data but when I use it in the Conditional Statements it doesn't work**

so these are the methods to store and retrieve the data

**STORING MEATHOD**

```
 // storing the credentials into the internal storage method

public void savedata(String FIlename, String datatobeStored) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        // storing at the parameter fileLocation
        fos = openFileOutput(FIlename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        // storint the parameter  text Given
        fos.write(datatobeStored.getBytes());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RETRIEVAL MEATHOD**

```
// Retreiving  the credentials  from the the internal storage meathod
public String dataRetreive(String filename) {
    String variableTogetStored = "qqq";
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(filename);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String text;
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(text).append("\n");
        }
        
        // retreiving the value from the storage and assigning it to the local variable
        variableTogetStored = sb.toString();
        
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // returing the local variable
    return variableTogetStored;
}
```

**When I try to retrieve and condition the statement it doesn't work**

Storing the Data

```
 savedata("teacherAdmin", "dashboardToTeachersAdmin");
```

Retrieving data

```
 String fromwheressss = dataRetreive("teacherAdmin");
```

Condition statement

```
                if (fromwheressss.equals("dashboardToTeachersAdmin")) {

                    Toast.makeText(teacher_admin.this,
                            "Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(teacher_admin.this,
                            "Not Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

This condition gives me **Not matched***

**Even I tried printing the retrieved field to the Toast it prints kinda Weird with complete space below**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While retreiving data you are appending **"\n"** after each line and **"dashboardToTeachersAdmin\n".equals("dashboardToTeachersAdmin")** is always **false**. So finally do this and you will get the right conditional result.

```
fromwheressss.trim().equals("dashboardToTeachersAdmin")
```

or just don't append **"\n"**. There are still possibilities you will get the wrong conditional result using **equals()** if you store and retreive a different data.

Comment: No this does not work either. So i found an alternative Solution, which I answered, You can check that out.

Answer (score 0):

**So to work this Properply I Changed it to the Shared Preferences, other than  that nothing Worked**

Here is the Code

**Storing Function**

```
    // storing the credentials in to the internal storage meathod

public void savedata(String prefernecename, String dataKey, String datatobeStored) {

    // preference name and data key are used to retrice the data and data to be stored is the
    // value you wanna store
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(prefernecename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(dataKey, datatobeStored);
    editor.commit();

}
```

**Retrieving value**

```
// Retreiving  the credentials  from the the internal storage meathod
public String dataRetreive(String prefernecename, String dataKey, String defaultValue) {

    // default value is somethhing which will be returned when no data is found place something
    //like "ERROR" in defaultValue
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(prefernecename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String storeddata = sharedPreferences.getString(dataKey, defaultValue);

    // returing the local variable
    return storeddata;
}
```

**Now it works perfectly**

```
   // retreiving the value
                String fromwheressss = dataRetreive("teacherAdmin",
                        "teacherAdminKey", defaultvalueForSharedpref);



                // removing the view based on the acitvity

                if (fromwheressss.equals("dashboardToTeachersAdmin")) {

                    Toast.makeText(teacher_admin.this,
                            "Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(teacher_admin.this,
                            "Not Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```